# c++ ampersand operator with char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was just playing with pointers and arrays when I got confused with this piece of code that I was testing with.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    char a[] = "hello";
    cout << &a[0] << endl;
    char b[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
    cout << &b[0] << endl;
    int c[] = {1, 2, 3};
    cout << &c[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that this would print three addresses(that of a[0], b[0] and c[0]). But the result was:

```
hello
hello
0x7fff1f4ce780
```

Why is that for the first two cases with char, '&' gives the whole string or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `cout`'s `operator <<` prints a string if you pass it a `char*` as parameter, which is what `&a[0]` is. If you want to print the address, you'll have to explicitly cast it to `void*`:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(&a[0]) << endl;
```

or just

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(a) << endl;
```